# Render Multi language Records in Extbase Extension in typo3

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.x

I am using TYPO3 7.6 and rendering multi language Records using findAll() and findByUid() methods. I wrote below code in my Repository

```
/*
* Initialize Default Settings
*/
public function initializeObject() {
    $querySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
    $querySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
    $querySettings->setRespectSysLanguage(TRUE);
    $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
}
```

I am having 2 language in my website. and My Records Renders correctly on front-end. My Problem is below.

```
uid     name    fcounter sys_language_id        l10n_parent
________________________________________________________
1       abc       2       0                      0
________________________________________________________
2       abc-en    0       1                      1
```

So is their any way to increase both languages fcounter field using findByUid() or any other methods of Repository?

Comment: What for is the fcounter field? How is it set initially?

Comment: its integer field default value is 0.

Comment: What is the purpose of the field?

Comment: Wants to increase the fcounter field everytimes when FAQs will click..  And want to display the popular FAQs list.

Comment: Currently i used $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery and update sys_language_id records but is their standard way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to update your TCA definition for your model.
The important value is "l10n_display".

> defaultAsReadonly – This renders the field as read only field with the content of the default language record. The field will be rendered even if ‘l10n_mode’ is set to ‘exclude’. While ‘exclude’ define the field not to be translated this option activate display of the default data.

[TYPO3 Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html#l10n-display)

```
"fcounter" => array(
                    "exclude"      => 1,
                    "l10n_mode"    => "exclude",
                    "l10n_display" => "defaultAsReadonly",
                    .....
            ),
```

Comment: i think this only copy language record from parent language and make it read only.it does not treat them separately , as language record may contain different data which need to be updated sepratlely.